# Problem writing a .xlsx file into an S3 bucket

Tags: r, excel, amazon-s3

I read a .xlsx file from an S3 bucket and populated it with data.
Now I need to export it back to the S3 bucket as a .xlsx file.

I tried using s3write_using function from the aws.s3 library, but i think it only takes FUN=write.csv as an argument. When I tried using FUN=write.xlsx it gives an error saying object 'write.xlsx' not found.
**NOTE**: My .xlsx file is a workbook with multiple sheets, and I am working in a docker Jupyter environment.

```
aws.s3::s3write_using(mtcars,
    object = paste0(file_name),
    FUN = write.xlsx,
    bucket = s3_bucket_path)
```